# ¿Cómo insertar un valor auto incremental de una tabla a otra?

Tags: sql-server

Me encuentro trabajando con 3 tablas: dos TEMP y una principal. La cosa es que quiero darle una actualización a mi sistema y que me permita subir varios registros a la vez. Lo que es la parte de insertar a las 2 tablas TEMP va muy bien, mi problema recae cuando quiero de ambas tablas insertar mis registros.

```sql
set @w_numero = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(cc_numero), 0) + 1
    FROM ROL_Cab_CtasxCbr WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
    WHERE cc_compania = 1)

   insert into ROL_Cab_CtasxCbr (    
   cc_compania,  cc_numero,  
   cc_tipo_cxc,  cc_ctasxcbr,  cc_empleado    
   ,cc_valor,   cc_decripcion, cc_observacion,  cc_fecha,   cc_cobro_cxc    
   ,cc_estado,   cc_tipoliqui ,  cc_masivo  
   )  
   select   
   dc_compania, @w_numero, 
   cc_tipo_cxc ,  cc_ctasxcbr, dc_empleado  
   ,dc_valor, '',[dc_observacion] , dc_fecha, dc_tipoc  
   ,'A',0, @w_masivo   
--   select *
    FROM TEMP_ROL_Det_CtasxCbr_Mas , TEMP_ROL_Cab_CtasxCbr_Mas_JS
   where  dc_compania = cc_compania  
   and dc_usuario = cc_usuario   
   and dc_maquina = cc_maquina  
   and dc_numero = cc_numero   
   and dc_compania = @i_compania and dc_usuario = @i_usuario and dc_maquina = @i_maquina   
   and dc_secuencia = @count
```

En mi transacción para generar mi registro necesito tomar el valor máximo de mi Tabla *ROL_Cab_CtasxCbr_JS*; la llamaremos "tabla principal" para no causar confusión. Junto a el campo *dc_compania* forman la clave primaria y antes solo podía ingresar un registro a la vez, pero, actualmente quiero subir varios de un tope y me da error de duplicidad de llave y entiendo que es por que al ser varios registros el valor de *@w_numero* es un valor fijo.

Me gustaría saber si tienen alguna idea de cómo ir sumando +1 a ese campo por cada registro ya que he intentado diferentes formas pero me da el error en cuestión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varios métodos. El más cercano al que estás usando, es que en vez de sumar uno, asignes un número de fila usando `ROW_NUMBER` y ese sea el número que sumes.

```
INSERT INTO ROL_Cab_CtasxCbr (    
    cc_compania,  
    cc_numero,  
    cc_tipo_cxc,  
    cc_ctasxcbr,  
    cc_empleado,
    cc_valor,   
    cc_decripcion, 
    cc_observacion,  
    cc_fecha,   
    cc_cobro_cxc,
    cc_estado,   
    cc_tipoliqui,  
    cc_masivo  
)  
SELECT   
    dc_compania, 
    (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(cc_numero), 0)
    FROM ROL_Cab_CtasxCbr WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
    WHERE cc_compania = 1) -- Creo que en vez de 1 debería de ser @i_compania
    + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), 
    cc_tipo_cxc,  
    cc_ctasxcbr, 
    dc_empleado,
    dc_valor, 
    '',
    [dc_observacion], 
    dc_fecha, 
    dc_tipoc,
    'A',
    0, 
    @w_masivo   
--   select *
FROM TEMP_ROL_Det_CtasxCbr_Mas 
JOIN TEMP_ROL_Cab_CtasxCbr_Mas_JS ON dc_compania = cc_compania  
                                 AND dc_usuario = cc_usuario  
                                 AND dc_maquina = cc_maquina  
                                 AND dc_numero = cc_numero   

WHERE dc_compania  = @i_compania 
AND   dc_usuario   = @i_usuario 
AND   dc_maquina   = @i_maquina   
AND   dc_secuencia = @count;
```

Modifiqué un poco la consulta para mantener todo en la misma instrucción, darle formato y utilizar la sintaxis de JOIN que es parte del estándar desde 1992.

Comment: Gracias entre mis intentos si utilice el `ROW_NUMBER` pero no dentro del insert, eso explica el porque solo me ingresaba el primero y el resto no y me daba la excepción de llave duplicada.